# How to give application path in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, xml, path

I am writing the necessary business logic in C# methods by using class library in .net. In each class of class library I am writing single method which servers the specific purpose. My project folder containing the class library is stored on F: drive. I have added one folder named XML to class library & added the XML file in that. Now how should I give the application  path in C# & then use that path for giving path to the XML file ? Can you please provide me the code or any link through which I can resolve the above issue ? Is there any other way (different from above way) in which we can give the path of the XML file dynamically ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762160/c-get-path-of-class-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: I don't understand how this can be the accepted answer. Neither is this necessarily the path of the class library (just tested: in this test, it's the executable's directory), nor can it be used to load embedded resources, which is what Shailesh Jaiswal requested in the comment to a (now deleted) answer. I'm not downvoting since this may be what he actually wanted to ask for, though then it's totally unclear from the question.

Comment: I just concentrated on this sentence:

>Now how should I give the application path in C# & then use that path for giving path to the XML file ?

Comment: No offense, it's ok. I just don't understand why this was accepted, since Shailesh Jaiswal said he wanted to extract embedded resources, and/or wanted to have a path relative to a class library, but he accepted an answer that will give him a path relative to the executable (likely) and won't extract resources. It just doesn't match exactly with the additional information. However. Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the XML files relative to your executable / class library? If so, just get the assembly object and retrieve its location.

Use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` to get an assembly object. This will be the assembly that calls GetExecutingAssembly - so if you're calling this in the class library, it will return the class library assembly. `Assembly.Location` contains the path to the assembly, and you can use the functions in `System.IO.Path` to modify the path to point to a subdirectory.

---

If, as you indicated in a comment, the XML files are embedded resources, you can use code like the following to retrieve them:

```
var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
foreach (string resourceName in asm.GetManifestResourceNames()) {
    var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
    // Do something with stream
}
```

In this case, I don't know if there's any possibility to use the path of one of the files to load it, but most .NET classes dealing with files can use a stream anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [Application.ExecutablePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx)?
Then you can use `IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath),"XML")` to get the location of the xml file you need.

Comment: Fair answer, but unfortunately WinForms-specific — cannot be used with a console app or with WPF...

Comment: You can try to use the first string returned by Environment.GetCommandLineArgs instead of Application.Executable path.

Comment: @munissor: From the docs: *The program file name can, but is not required to, include path information.* Unfortunately, you can't rely on `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` for path information because of this.

Comment: I know, I just commented to "try" if it works, maybe for Shailesh's case it's acceptable..

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-c-in-a-console-app) will solve your problem.